# Typescript / Eslint throws "Cannot read file tsconfig.json" in every project I start

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, eslint

In other threads I read that the issue might come when eslint and tsconfig.json are not in the same working folder, but I have all the files in the project's root folder. Somehow, after initializing the project, the thrown error seems to try to find tsconfig.json in the **parent folder** of the project (so, outside the project):

Let's say the project is in: '\parentFolder\ProjectRoot'
tsconfig is in the route: '\parentFolder\ProjectRoot\tsconfig.json

The eslint error I get (at the top of index.ts) is the following:

*Parsing error: Cannot read file '**parentFolder**\tsconfig.json'*

- Note that eslint is somehow looking for tsconfig in the wrong folder (the parent of the root folder)

---

---

The contents of \parentFolder\ProjectRoot are:

The steps to get to this point have been:

- npm init
- npm i -D typescript
- add "tsc": "tsc" script to package.json
- npm run tsc -- --init
- npm i express
- npm i -D eslint @types/express @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser
- npm i -D ts-node-dev

**.eslintrc:**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
        "error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ],
     "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 1,
    "no-case-declarations": 0
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

**package.json** (looks like changing index.js to index.ts in "main" does nothing)

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

**index.ts**
(I get implicity errors here in req and res, I imagine caused by the fact that tsconfig can't be found).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 3000;
app.get('/ping', (_req, res) => {
  res.send('pong');
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

---

---

**edit:**

I had typescript installed globally (and also as a dev dependency in these projects). Thinking this might be the issue, I uninstalled the global version of typescript.

When checking all global packages with npm list -g --depth 0, I get the following:

[image]

I don't know if that would be related to the issue.

Comment: Is there any `.eslintrc` or `package.json` in the `parentFolder`?

Comment: Nop. There is another project in the same parent folder as "ProjectRoot" with its own .eslintrc and tsconfig.json. In both cases, eslint looks for tsconfig file in the parent folder containing both projects. I thought it might be a problem with having typescript installed both locally and globally but I have uninstalled the global version and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Try changing `./tsconfig.json` to `tsconfig.json` in `.eslintrc`?

Comment: Could you please add the code for these files instead of screenshots, so that one can run on their own machine?

Comment: changing ./tsconfig to tsconfig does not work.

Added the code for you (just learned to to easily paste blocks of code, sorry about that)

Comment: Curiously, if I run eslint with the current config it throws no errors, but if I change the project path in .eslintrc to     "project": "./ProjectRoot/tsconfig.json", then the error disappears in VS Code but I get the same error when I run eslint in the console instead.

Comment: It seems that if I remove the parser options from .eslintrct the warning disappears:   "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  }

Comment: replace "parserOptions": { "project": ["apps/portal/tsconfig.*?.json"] }, with "parserOptions": { "project": ["apps/portal/tsconfig.{app,server,spec}.json"] }, or the tsconfig file names you want to have, it helped me

Answer (score 56):

What worked for me was on the .eslintrc of the folder you are on to add:

```
parserOptions: {
   project: 'tsconfig.json',
   tsconfigRootDir: __dirname // <-- this did the trick for me
}
```

Comment: in angular I had to make it like this `"tsconfigRootDir": "../../"`

Comment: what if `.eslintrc` is in json format?

Comment: @RahulYadav to use __dirname you'll need to convert it to .eslintrc.js and have the object exported `module.exports = {...}`

Comment: This worked for me too, but I still have no idea what happened. Everything was working fine with my eslintrc being a static json until yesterday and today eslint started doing this thing to me. No idea what's going on.

Comment: @RahulYadav you can convert, like Jordan suggests, or you can use the setup described by Greg above https://stackoverflow.com/a/76580995/511976
The latter is just potentially dangerous if there are many tsconfig files.

Comment: not sure why but it worked.. squiggles gone.  could of swore it was working lol

Answer (score 28):

I'm putting this answer here as an idiot-proofing measure. This can also happen if you open the project in the wrong folder. I got this error when I opened the parent directory of the project instead of the project directory itself. I had a project in `GitLab -> projectFolder` and opened GitLab. I got the error saying `tsconfig.json` could not be read.

Comment: you just solved my issue

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar problem in my sub project, what resolved my issue was modifying the `parserOptions` in my sub project's `.eslintrc.json`:

```
  {
      "globals": {
         "__dirname": true
      },
      "overrides": [{
         "parserOptions": {
            "project": "**/tsconfig.json",
            "sourceType": "module"
         },
      }]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped when you have eslintrc.json format, because the other answers would probably work only with eslintrc.js format.

Answer (score 3):

in parserOptions of ts config add

```
tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
```

Comment: Hi, there is already an answer with that content.  When answering, be sure to add some valuable content. Read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: wouldn't this be in the eslint config??

Answer (score 0):

For me, I am using VS code to edit the code. I just close the vs code and reopen it again. Then there is no error anymore. So, just make sure the path is correct, and then you can try this.It's so tricky, but it works.